# How to append an element to an array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I wish to append my `elem` to the end of an array `A`.

What should I do?

Comment: @Guddu  huhhuh, this was once a funny slip of the tongue during a presentation. *facepalm*

Comment: This is [so duplicated](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=matlab+append+stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that I don't know where to begin. Do you have a more specific question because I'm sure that you must have searched first.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the following

```
A = [A elem] % for row array
```

or

```
A = [A; elem] % for col array
```

---

Edit: Another simpler way is (as @BenVoigt suggested) to use `end` keyword

```
A(end+1) = elem;
```

which works for both row and column vectors.

Comment: Do I need to declare it first? like `A = {}`

Comment: @FarticlePilter No, you don't.

Comment: `a = [1 2 3]; a = [A 4];`

Comment: a = [1 2 3]; a = [a 4];

Comment: Hi, I was trying to add elements to the end of array inside a loop, but for some reason it won't work. cols = [];
for iu = 1:length(id_unique)
[~,col] = find(faces(:,:)== iu);
cols(end+1) = col;
end Do you see a problem in here?

Answer (score 12):

Another way is

```
A(end+1) = elem;
```

which works for both row and column vectors.

Comment: Of course, you have to compute "end" first. Good point though.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: No, `end` is the MATLAB keyword.