# Which syntax is better for deleting elements of an array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

In MATLAB say I have an array, and have created a logical vector that has `true` entries for elements that I want to remove, call it `del_index` for example. To accomplish this, is one of the following ways better/faster and/or preferable?

```
arr(del_index) = [];
```

OR

```
arr = arr(~del_index);
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657685/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-appending-an-element-to-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both look nice, so lets test the speed.

```
time1=0;
th=0.5
for ii=1:100000

   arr=rand(10000,1);
   del_index=arr<th;
   tic
   arr(del_index) = [];
   time1=time1+toc;
end


time2=0;
for ii=1:100000

   arr=rand(10000,1);
   del_index=arr<th;
   tic
   arr = arr(~del_index);
   time2=time2+toc;
end

display(['arr(del_index) is ', num2str(time1/time2), ' times slower'])
```

I tried with different values of `th`, from 0 to 1 and I generally get this value. So yeah, second on is better.

`arr(del_index) is 1.5136 times slower`